# Why aren't padding bytes in executables optimized?

Tags: c, gcc, memory, compilation, mach-o

When I create a small Mac Mach-O executable, "Hello World" written in C for example, it's about 48k in size, because of alignment padding. Yet at the same time I can define 100k of zero-es in the .bss section (for example by specifying a static array of 100k chars) and it's adding just a few bytes to my executable on disk.

I wonder why the padding(, which only plays a role after being loaded, I suppose) is not also "packed" somehow.

Comment: How would it be "unpacked" w/o knowing the structure, which the executable does not have explicitly?

Comment: The BSS section is not "optimized", it is just not there. No executable format I know stores BSS sections. It is the task of the startup code to zero the section. Some startup codes also reserve or provide the memory for the section.

Answer (score 2):

You seem not to appreciate the role of padding: to ensure that the size of an object satisfies a constraint, such as being a multiple of a specific number.  The *values* of padding bytes typically are not significant, but their presence is indispensable.

Exactly the opposite is the case for objects assigned to an ELF (say) .bss section: their values are important, but their sizes do not need to be reflected by their on-disk representations.  Moreover, the values of such objects are established simply by the fact that they are assigned to .bss, so indeed, each one consumes O(1) space in the binary with respect to the size of its in-memory representation.

**Addendum:** it is conceivable that a binary format could be designed that carried compressed data, so that such padding indeed was compressed on disk. One can only speculate about why such formats are not popular, but I think it's pretty safe to guess that at least part of the answer is that the simplicity and loading speed of uncompressed binary formats are more valued than the comparatively small amounts of space saving that compressed formats could achieve.

Comment: You have answered why some big things can take little space in the executable file, but the question asks some things take a lot of space in the executable file—it asks why a *prima facie* excessive number of zeros bytes **do** appear in the executable file.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, the OP seems satisfied to attribute the size of their executable to padding, and I see no reason to dispute that explanation.  The question is specifically why the padding is not compressed on disk, in light of the fact that other data can be characterized as being represented in compressed form, so a comparison is in order.  Nevertheless, I have added some comments speaking to some of the other, related issues that are perhaps less obvious to the OP than they seem to me.

Comment: This barely scratches the surface. I was expecting an answer in the likes of what kernel devs would have to say. Like "we didn't want to parse the binaries for decompression since it introduced that security flaw". Or "..because we measured a pessimization; for that contrived reason.". Or "..because we don't care shit about the tiny KB that you care about". Now we're still left in the limbos

Comment: @v.oddou, this answer challenges the premise of the question.  If you want an answer to a similar, more firmly founded question then you are welcome to pose such a question.  Or if you have your own answer then you are of course welcome to post it.